# When a users login in from a browser , his previous session should get expire

Tags: session

I have a external facing website (Back end SQL Server and ASP.NET) where I want a feature that if a user from same id is already logged in, and he tries to login again from some other browser or through some other channel, his previous session should be expired.

So for this in which way should I proceed ?

Comment: This is a bit vague, how are you storing sessions?

Quick answer here as well would it possible to add to your new session code a query to delete all other sessions from the table?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the sessions in a database, by providing a unique session-id every time a user logs in. By storing the session-id also in a session variable you can see when the user is logged in somewhere else.

For example:

- User A logs in in Safari on his laptop
- *Session id is generated and stored in database and session variable*
- User A browses to different page
- *Session id in database is compared with session variable*
- *ids match, user is still logged in*
- User A logs in using Chrome on his phone
- *Session id is generated and stored (overwriting the previous) in database and session variable*
- User A browses **on his laptop** to a new page
- *Ids do not match, redirect to login page*

You can also make this more general by keeping a session table, in order to allow a maximum number of sessions per user. The key is just to use a global storage like a database in combination with the session information to verify where the user logged in last.